# ¿ Como ocultar un <div> dependiendo del rol de usuario en WordPress?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, footer

El sitio web que esto manejando tiene UX Builder como editor.
Tiene la opción de añadir fragmento de html en el `Header Main` y en `TopBar`.
Yo he creado un pequeño código para añadir un mensaje. En este  caso lo he añadido en el `TopBar`. El fragmento es muy simple.

```
<div class="gratis">
<i class="fa-solid fa-truck-fast fa-beat fa-2xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
  <span>Envío gratis a España</span>
</div>
```

El problema es que quiero ocultar este mensaje a determinado rol de usuario, en este caso a `'shop_manager'`

Un compañero a creado un script de `javascript` y con una función de `php` lo ocultamos en el `footer`, en principio oculta el contenido del  , sin embargo, cuando recargamos la pagina, pinchamos en otra sección, cambiamos de pantalla de la Web, el mensaje se muestra por un segundo o milisegundos. Pero se ve levemente.
Esto queda muy feo y necesito evitarlo, pero no se la form de hacerlo.

La siguiente función es la que utilizo

```
function hide_gratis_for_wholesale_customer() {
    $current_user = wp_get_shop_manager();
    if (in_array('shop_manager', (array) $current_user->roles)) {
        echo '<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
                $(".envio").hide();
            });
        </script>';
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'hide_gratis_for_shop_manager');
```

¿ Pueden darme alguna idea?

Comment: Pero porque no modificas tu script, solo que en vez de agregar un script de javascript simplemente haces echo del div, no necesitas javascript para eso.

Comment: no entiendo que me dices, perdóname  pero estoy un poco perdido, ¿ como oculto el `<div>` con  `echo`?

Comment: Estoy dando viueltas y no se si quieres decir hacer echo '<style> .envio { display: none; } </style>'; ¿ a eso te refieres @JefferzonBol ? Esto funciona pero al usuario que no es 'shop_manager', le añade otro `<div>`más sobre el que ya tien el TopBar

Comment: Agrega la función que usas para agregar el div que contiene la info de envio, es decir, la función que usas para imprimir esto "<div class="gratis">
<i class="fa-solid fa-truck-fast fa-beat fa-2xl" style="color: #ffffff;"></i>
  <span>Envío gratis a España</span>
</div>"

Comment: sigo sin entender, no caigo a que te refieres. Lo tengo delante y no lo veo